# Cant figure out why I cant retrieve data from my API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

When I type a city name into my search bar it should pull up information on the weather on that city but I get a 400 bad request error
JAVASCRIPT:

```
function handleGetData(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const cityName = $("#city").val()
        $.ajax({url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=99df413c60279878184277e08a2c6863`})
        .then(
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                $("#name").text(data.name)
                $("#temp").text(data.temp)
                $("#feels").text(data.feels_like)
                $("#weather").text(data.weather)
                
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("bad request: ", error)
            }
            )
            console.log("It's working!")
    }
    $('form').on("submit", handleGetData)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? What gets logged in the console? Have you checked the network tab to see if the request is being sent properly?

Comment: Thank you, I did update my code and post but unfortunately in the console Im getting a bad request 400 error

Comment: This code works fine. I pasted it in my console, ran it with "berlin" as a city name and I got a JSON results with data. Even without city name, it just says "404 City not found". Can't reproduce

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a promise incorrectly.
The correct syntax is `.then(result => {}).catch(e => {})`

Like this

```js
const cityName = $("#city").val()
$.ajax({url: url})
   .then((data, a, b, c) => {
      console.log(data);
      $("#name").text(data.name)
      $("#temp").text(data.temp)
      $("#feels").text(data.feels_like)
      $("#weather").text(data.weather)
      console.log("It's working!")
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.error(error) //not necessarily a "bad request"
   })
```